# Passed parameter is empty in controller (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this view:

```
@model FakeModel;

@using (Html.BeginForm("FakeMethod", "FakeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input class="form-control mb-4" name="NewName" asp-for="NewName"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Name</button>
}
```

And this model class:

```
public class FakeModel
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FakeMethod(FakeModel fakeModel)
{
    var vName = fakeModel.NewName;
    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
}
```

But `fakeModel.NewName` is empty. What is missing or how to change it?

**Update**:

**View**:

```
@model Solution.Models.FakeModel;
<input class="form-control mb-4" type="text" asp-for="NewName" />
```

Comment: Why do you provide a `name`?

Comment: Remove  `name="NewName"`. The name should be `FakeModel.NewName` and will be auto generated by `asp-for`

Comment: Decorate asp-for as `asp-for="@Model.NewName"`

Comment: `Html.BeginForm("FakeMethod", "FakeController", FormMethod.Post)` should be `Html.BeginForm("FakeMethod", "Fake", FormMethod.Post)`. If your controller is named `FakeController` you should only pass `Fake` as second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fakeModel.NewName is empty. What is missing or how to change it?

You are missing the Model reference which causing the issue because fakeModel.NewName attribute bind from FakeModel which you haven't included with of your @model . You should add as following:

```cs
@model MVCApps.Models.FakeModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("FakeMethod", "Amimal", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input class="form-control mb-4"  asp-for="@Model.NewName" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Name</button>
}
```

**Note:** Upate here as asp-for="@Model.NewName"

View Ouput:

[image]

**Note:** You don't need name="NewName" attribute because, while loading the page it will generate those attribute autometically. which you can see in the image below.

Output:

[image]

[image]

Complete Solution:

Model:

```
 public class FakeModel
    {
        public string NewName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult FakeMethod(FakeModel fakeModel)
        {
            var vName = fakeModel.NewName;
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
       

    }
```

**Note:** Make sure your controller name and action name is correctly written.

View:

```
@model MVCApps.Models.FakeModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("FakeMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input class="form-control mb-4" asp-for="@Model.NewName" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Name</button>
}
```

**Note:** In Index action put the above view code snippet.  Point to remember here @model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.FakeModel, I have placed FakeModel within Model folder in the project and my project name is DotNet6MVCWebApp.

Comment: can you show me how looks like view?

Comment: @4est Added the view with details source

Comment: can you upload solution? as still I got null

Comment: Okay adding that as well

Comment: Updated the full code that I have tested your scenario with.

Comment: OP is (according to their tags) not using ASP.NET Core.

Comment: target framework is .net core 2.1

Comment: Yes I know but I have updated because it it will remain same for other platforms as well becuase all core xxx version belongs to asp.net core. Thus, have updated tag so that the issue doesn't get redundant. If you think its not required please ommit that thanks.

Comment: I corrected as your answer, action from controller is called but fakeModel.NewName is empty :(

Comment: Okay you can set as asp-for="@Model.NewName"

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know if that works accordingly.

Comment: @Md can you chat me priv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252653/discussion-between-4est-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).